# references and address (memory location) of a variable

Tags: reference

Can someone please explain why the output of the below code snippet is `20` ?

```
int i = 10;
cout << i << endl;

int &r = i;
r = 20;
cout << i << endl;
```

First, variable `i` stores the integer value `10`
Then `10` is displayed.
Then the address of `r` (memory location of `r`) is set to `i` which is `10` And then `r` becomes `20` But why `i` changes to `20` as well?

The integer content of `r` has changed, not address of it (memory location of it).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable r is a refernce to i, it's like a pointer except that instead of saying *r = 20;
you just say r  = 20; and that changes the value of r.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a reference it's almost like a pointer so when you can changed r you actually changed what r was pointing to which is also i.

Actually to be more precise the reference is not a pointer or an address, it *is* the object.  At least in c++ world.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it as:

```
int i = 10;
cout << i << endl;

int *p = &i;
*p = 20;
cout << i << endl;
```

This is basically what's happening behind the scenes

Comment: Yes, C programmers can look at it that way but it's important to distinct that a reference is *not* a pointer but *is* the object.

Comment: Quite. That's why I said its basically what's happening *behind the scenes*